# Does there exist a type level left-fold metafunction in the standard library?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

If `a,b,c,..` denote types then let `(a,b)` be the type `std::pair<a,b>` I am looking for the map, `F`, such that

```
    F : ((((a,b),c),d),...))) -> std::tuple<a,b,c,d...>
```

Does this exist under some existing name in the standard library? If not, is there another library
in which it does or is this easily implemented and I'm just too dumb to know how to do it?

Comment: So you want a metafunction that takes `pair<pair<a, b>, c>` into `tuple<a, b, c>`? That doesn't seem like a "fold" to me - more like an unfold.

Comment: @Barry. Yes that makes more sense but then it takes many types to a single type. But I bow to your knowledge on these things, I am not expert in meta-programming. Should I change the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this one basically has to be recursive. There is no such thing in the standard library, and for once I can't come up with a [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html) one-liner.

```
namespace impl {
    template <typename T>
    struct unfold_t {
        using type = std::tuple<T>;
    };

    template <typename A, typename B>
    struct unfold_t<std::pair<A, B>> {
        using type = mp_push_back<typename unfold_t<A>::type, B>;
    };
}

template <typename T>
using unfold = typename impl::unfold_t<T>::type;
```

---

With an assist from T.C., the newest edition of Mp11 (1.73) has an algorithm named [`mp_iterate`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_iteratev_f_r) which we can use thusly.

Given `std::pair<std::pair<X, Y>, Z>`, if we apply `mp_first` repeatedly (as `R`) we get the sequence:

- `std::pair<std::pair<X, Y>, Z>`
- `std::pair<X, Y>`
- `X`

Then, if we apply `mp_second` to that sequence, we get:

- `Z`
- `Y`
- ill-formed

That's pretty close. We do need that `X`. So we need a more complex metafunction for `F`: we need to get the second value if possible. There's a metafunction for that:

```
template <typename L>
using second_or_self = mp_eval_or<L, mp_second, L>;
```

And now `mp_iterate<T, second_or_self, mp_first>` gives us `mp_list<Z, Y, X>`. All we need to do at that point is reverse it and turn it into a `std::tuple`:

```
template <typename L>
using unfold = mp_rename<mp_reverse<
    mp_iterate<L, second_or_self, mp_first>>,
    std::tuple>;
```

Now that Boost.173 is on compiler-explorer, [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/VTEnWq).

---

Or, I suppose, if you really hate your readers, you can make this a [single alias](https://godbolt.org/z/K5gDaA):

```
template <typename L>
using unfold = mp_rename<mp_reverse<
    mp_iterate_q<L,
        mp_bind<mp_eval_or_q, _1, mp_quote<mp_second>, _1>,
        mp_quote<mp_first>>>,
    std::tuple>;
```

Comment: The very thing. Could have written it myself given 6 months and enough coffee. Plus, thanks to you I have discovered mp11. Very useful indeed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution by @Barry, and in particular the name `unfold` for this meta-function. However, I think you can implement this quite easily using partial specializations, without using boost.Mp11, and you might find this easier to understand.

First, provide the base case for a type that's already completely unfolded into a `tuple`:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct unfold_impl { using type = std::tuple<Ts...>; };
```

and then provide a specialization if there's still a `pair` left to unfold:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename ...Ts>
struct unfold_impl<std::pair<A,B>, Ts...> : unfold_impl<A, B, Ts...> {};
```

and finally provide a convenience alias template:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
using unfold = typename unfold_impl<Ts...>::type;
```

and that's it.

You can check that it works, like this:

```
static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<
        unfold<std::pair<std::pair<std::pair<int, long>, char>, double>>,
        std::tuple<int, long, char, double>
        >);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9QC82d)